# Ansible Dynamic inventory data in template to provision haproxy

Tags: ansible

I am currently using a combination of local inventory files and ec2.py generated inventory. The current playbook I am working on builds and deploys a modsec nginx proxy to ec2 instances that are tags as "modec" ='nginx-prod'

In the nginx config template I would like to then loop through the web backends in our VPC based on the tag "backened" = 'web-prod'.

```
 upstream backend {
   {% for host in backends %}
    server {{ host }} weight=5
   {% endfor %}

}
```

Is this operation even possible or would I have to generate additional configuration templates with the backend variables in another process?

Answer (score 1):

Defining the variable in the playbook for the backends worked. I still don't think the dynamic inventory was showing up either from being cached or because I didn't have  a definition of it in the static. However I was not able to break it one it was working.

```
---
- hosts: modsec-proxy
  remote_user: admin
  vars:
    backends: "{{ groups['tag_backend_web_prod'] }}"

  tasks:
  - apt_repository: repo='deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main' state=present
    sudo: yes
```

Was helpful to dump out variables into a test template.

```
  - name: Dump all vars
    action: template src=files/modsecurity-nginx/templates/dumpall.j2 dest=/tmp/ansible.all
    sudo: yes



EC2 Info
{{ groups['tag_backend_web_prod'] | to_nice_json }}



Module Variables ("vars"):
--------------------------------
{{ vars | to_nice_json }}

Environment Variables ("environment"):
--------------------------------
{{ environment | to_nice_json }}

GROUP NAMES Variables ("group_names"):
--------------------------------
{{ group_names | to_nice_json }}

GROUPS Variables ("groups"):
--------------------------------
{{ groups | to_nice_json }}

GROUPS Variables ("hostvars"):
--------------------------------
{{ hostvars | to_nice_json }}
```